# How to disable popup's in android eclipse when project gets rebuild?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

This is very annoying popup which gets displayed when eclipse rebuilds it. Have you encountered this, and how you dealt with it?

[image]
Regards

Comment: No popup when I rebuild.  You either have some odd setting on or some kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

The tab that pops up is the **console** for handling IO during runtime in eclipse.

To stop it from popping up you can change your settings in 
Run-->Run Configurations-->(Under "Android Application" select your project)--> common,
and uncheck "Allocate console" under "Standard Input and Output".